# Delphi + Binance Api + Limit Order Problem Invalid signatur

Tags: delphi, post, binance, idhttp, binance-api-client

```
{"code":3702,"msg":"Invalid signature.","timestamp":1623848681308}
```

i use trbinance.com api. I keep getting the same error

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  url, sign, queryString, nonce: string;
  ST: SystemTime;
  DT: TDateTime;
  uTime: int64;
  sHour, sMin, sSec, sMili: Word;
 
  stream, s_url: string;
  Post: TStringList;
  IdHTTP10 : TIDhttp;
  api_key , api_secret : String;
begin
  api_key := '**';
  api_secret := '**';
 
  GetSystemTime(ST);
  DT := EncodeDate(ST.wYear, ST.wMonth, ST.wDay) +
        EncodeTime(ST.wHour, ST.wMinute, ST.wSecond, ST.wMilliseconds);
  uTime := DateUtils.MilliSecondsBetween(DT, UnixDateDelta);
  nonce:=inttostr(uTime);
 
  url :='https://trbinance.com/open/v1/orders';
  queryString := 'symbol=BTT_TRY&side=0&type=1&quantity=1&price=0.0022&recvWindow=5000&timestamp='+nonce;
  sign := THashSHA2.GetHMAC(queryString, api_secret, SHA256);
 
  IdHTTP10 := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP10.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP10.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('X-MBX-APIKEY:'+api_key);
  IdHTTP10.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
 
  Post:=TStringList.Create;
  Post.Add('quantity=1&');
  Post.Add('price=0.0022&');
  Post.Add('recvWindow=5000&');
  Post.Add('timestamp='+nonce+'&');
  Post.Add('signature='+sign);
 
  s_url := url + '?symbol=BTT_TRY&side=0&type=1';
  try
    stream:=IdHTTP10.POST(s_url, Post);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(stream);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(time)+' <---> [Order] error: '+E.Message);
  end;
  IdHTTP10.Free;
  Post.Free;
end;
```

Always problem :

```
{"code":3702,"msg":"Invalid signature.","timestamp":1623848681308}

Normaly Binance Symbol : BTTTRY  
Turkey Api : BTT_TRY
Normaly Binance Order Url :  httpps://api.binance.com/api/v3/order
Turkey Api Order Url : https://trbinance.com/open/v1/orders
```

Where is the Problem ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You must use `try..finally` blocks to protect your resources.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: I know, but you must still use them for resource protection.

Comment: No, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHdIO.png

Comment: *Always* this pattern: `Frog := TFrog.Create; try { use Frog } finally Frog.Free end`. If you have five resources, you nest five such blocks. Good Delphi code is triangular!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with this code, but the biggest one I see is that you should NOT be including trailing `&` characters in your `TStringList` strings, eg:

```pascal
Post:=TStringList.Create;
Post.Add('quantity=1');
Post.Add('price=0.0022');
Post.Add('recvWindow=5000');
Post.Add('timestamp='+nonce);
Post.Add('signature='+sign);
```

`TIdHTTP.Post()` will insert those `&` characters into the request body for you, thus the data being transmitted is different than the data you signed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers. I made improvements to the code.

Friends in need can use this procedure in delphi. ( for Global Binance Api )

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  Publickey= '***';
  Secretkey= '***';
var
  IdHTTP        : TIdHTTP;
  RBody         : TStringstream;
  QueryString   : String;
  Signature     : String;
  url           : String;
begin

  queryString :=
    'symbol=BTTTRY&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1000&price=0.024400&recvWindow=5000&timestamp='
    + ABDULLAH_GetTimestamp();

  Signature := THashSHA2.GetHMAC(queryString, Secretkey, SHA256);

  Try

    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
    RBody := TStringStream.Create(queryString + '&signature=' + Signature);

    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('X-MBX-APIKEY:' + Publickey);
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.UnfoldLines := True;
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoForceEncodeParams,
      hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];

    IdHTTP.iohandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;

    url := 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?';

    Try
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IdHTTP.Post(url, RBody));
    Except
      ON E: EXCEPTION DO
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Error Message:' + E.Message);
    End;

  Finally
    FreeAndNil(IdHTTP);
    FreeAndNil(RBody);
  End;
end;
```

**This code works for Global Binance Api.**

Change Symbol : BTTTRY -> BTT_TRY
And Post Url  : *https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order* -> *https://trbinance.com/open/v1/orders*

İt's not working and Result :

```
{"code":3702,"msg":"Invalid signature.","timestamp":1723648673412}
```

**This Procedure works in 'Global Binance Api' but not working 'trbinance Api'**

Same procedure gives 'invalid signature' error in 'trbinance api'. :(

**trbinance api example :**

HMAC SHA256 signature:

```
[linux]$ echo -n "symbol=BTC_USDT&side=0&type=1&quantity=0.16&price=7500&timestamp=1581720670624&recvWindow=5000" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "cfDC92B191b9B3Ca3D842Ae0e01108CBKI6BqEW6xr4NrPus3hoZ9Ze9YrmWwPFV"
(stdin)= 33824b5160daefc34257ab9cd3c3db7a0158a446674f896c9fc3b122ae656bfa
```

curl command:

```
(HMAC SHA256)
[linux]$  curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: cfDC92B191b9B3Ca3D842Ae0e01108CBKI6BqEW6xr4NrPus3hoZ9Ze9YrmWwPFV" -X POST 'https://www.trbinance.com/open/v1/orders' -d 'symbol=BTC_USDT&side=0&type=1&quantity=0.16&price=7500&timestamp=1581720670624&recvWindow=5000&signature=33824b5160daefc34257ab9cd3c3db7a0158a446674f896c9fc3b122ae656bfa'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Binance TR API docs](https://www.trbinance.com/apidocs/#endpoint-security-type):

> Use your secretKey as the key and totalParams as the value for the HMAC operation.
> totalParams is defined as the query string concatenated with the request body.

Error from API with the text "Invalid signature." could give you a clue that the problem is with your signature algo:

```
sign := THashSHA2.GetHMAC(queryString, api_secret, SHA256);
```

Your code here signs only your query string, but according to API docs you must sign query string **concatenated with the request body**.

So, you need to change your code like this ("Post" variable must be initialized before this line):

```
sign := THashSHA2.GetHMAC(queryString + Post.text, api_secret, SHA256);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the `TIdHTTP` component in Delphi to connect to Binance has problems. I kept getting Http/1.1 400 Bad Request.

I switched to `TNetHTTPClient` instead to connect with Binance.

The following is the working program that can be used for placing an order on Binance:

```
uses
System.Net.HttpClient, System.Hash, DateUtils;

procedure TForm1.fapiorder(oSide: String; oCoin: String; oAmt: Integer);
var
  sOrderAmt: string;
  ClearEntryUrl: string;
  Params: string;
  Signature: string;
  URL: string;
  ResponseStream : TStringStream;
  postStream: TStringStream;
  uTime: int64;
  nowDateTime: string;
  ST: SystemTime;
  DT: TDateTime;
  HttpClient: THttpClient;
  HttpResponse: IHttpResponse;
  BaseURLUSDM, ApiKey, ApiSecret: string;
begin
  //https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/cn/#trade-3
  BaseURLUSDM   := 'https://fapi.binance.com/';    //合約永續
  ClearEntryUrl := 'fapi/v1/order';
  ApiSecret     := 'YOUR API SECRET KEY';

  //timestamp 開始
  GetSystemTime(ST);
  DT := EncodeDate(ST.wYear, ST.wMonth, ST.wDay) + EncodeTime(ST.wHour, 
  ST.wMinute, ST.wSecond, ST.wMilliseconds);
  uTime := DateUtils.MilliSecondsBetween(DT, UnixDateDelta);
  nowDateTime := IntToStr(uTime);
  Writeln('DateTime = ' + nowDateTime);
  //timestamp 結束

  Params := 'recvWindow=3000&timestamp=' + nowDateTime;

  if (TDCoinMap.TryGetValue(oCoin, CoinMap) = True) then
      begin
        sOrderAmt := '0.07';
        if (StrToFloat(sOrderAmt) <> 0) then
            begin
                Params := Params + '&symbol='     + oCoin;
                Params := Params + '&side='       + oSide;
                Params := Params + '&type=MARKET';
                Params := Params + '&quantity='   + sOrderAmt;
                Signature := THashSHA2.GetHMAC(Params, ApiSecret, SHA256);
                
                URL := BaseURLUSDM + ClearEntryUrl + '?' + Params + '&signature=' + Signature;
                postStream := TStringStream.Create('');
                ResponseStream := TStringStream.Create('');
                try
                    HttpClient := THTTPClient.Create;
                    HttpClient.HandleRedirects := True;
                    HttpClient.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0';
                    HttpClient.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                    HttpClient.CustomHeaders['X-MBX-APIKEY'] := 'Your Binance APIKEY';
                    HttpResponse := HttpClient.Post(URL, ResponseStream);
                    jResult := HttpResponse.ContentAsString();
                    Writeln('jResult = ' + jResult);
                finally
                    HttpClient.Free;
                end;
           end;
    end;
end;
```